# How to set a default minutes for datetime picker

Tags: vba, vb6

Using Datetime Picker control

Datetimepicker control format is `00` (minutes only, upto 59 minutes)

When i load the form, it should display 05 minutes defautly...

Example

```
Form1

Datetimepicker control `00` (Up/Down Format)
```

When i load the form1, then Datetimepicker control should display `05` instead of `00`

How to do this.

Need vb6 code help

Comment: What code have you written? What isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my memory serves me right then `00` is the incorrect format. It should be like this (*Writing this off my memory but I am sure this is good to go*)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    With DTPicker1
        .Format = dtpCustom
        .CustomFormat = "mm"
        .Value = #00:05:00#
    End With
End Sub
```

Also `DTPicker1.CustomFormat` is case sensitive so it has to be `mm` and not `MM`

**EDIT**

Just wanted to be 100% sure so I went back and tested it myself... LOL. Yes, it works.

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: I;ve adjusted the sample to use a date literal. Don;t forget that you can also just set `.Minute = 5`

Comment: You are right Deanna. There are many ways to skin the a cat :)